# The function which returns the number of occurences per variable

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I have got a list of points:`data = {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,1},{2,3},{2,5},{2,6},{2,7}}`.
And I wanted to plot a function which will be showing the number of points for a variable, i. e. `{1,2},{1,3},{1,4}`, three points so for x=1 function is 3, for x=2 function is 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you are Marianna

```
F[x_] := Length@Select[data, #[[1]] == x &]
F[1]
F[2]
```

> 3
>   5

as an example,
if you have this data

> {{1, 9}, {2, 3}, {2, 10}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 8}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {6, 
>     1}, {6, 5}, {7, 7}, {8, 4}, {8, 5}, {8, 9}, {8, 10}, {9, 5}, {9, 
>     6}, {10, 2}, {10, 8}, {10, 10}}

here is how you can plot F function

```
ListPlot[Table[F[k], {k, 10}]]
```

[image]

here is also an example with negative values

> {{-5, 3}, {-4, -1}, {-4, 0}, {-4, 1}, {-4, 
>     4}, {-3, -5}, {-3, -3}, {-1, -5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 
>     3}, {1, -3}, {2, -3}, {3, -5}, {3, -2}, {3, 5}, {4, -4}, {4, 0}, {4,
>      2}, {5, 0}}

```
ListPlot[Table[{k, F[k]}, {k, -5, 5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for help ;)

Comment: anytime ;)  Thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
f = CountsBy[data, First]
```

> <|1 -> 3, 2 -> 5|>

You can do this for getting a plot:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {400, 2}];
f = CountsBy[data, First];
ListLinePlot[Lookup[f, Range[1, 100], 0], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]